# Groovy HTTPBuilder Mocking the Client

Tags: unit-testing, grails, groovy, httpbuilder

This question is closely related to [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9101084/groovy-httpbuilder-mocking-the-response). The difference is that I'd like to follow the recommended approach of mocking the client. So, I have the following HTTPBuilder defined:

```
protected readUrl() {
    def http = new HTTPBuilder("http://example.com")
    def status = http.request(Method.GET, ContentType.JSON) {req ->
        response.success = {resp, json ->
            result = json.toString()
            new Success<String>(result)
        }
        response.'401' = {resp ->
            final String errMsg = "Not Authorized"
            new Failed(Failable.Fail.ACCESS_DENIED, errMsg)
        }
        response.failure = {resp ->
            final String errMsg = "General failure ${resp.statusLine}"
            new Failed(Failable.Fail.UNKNOWN, errMsg)
        }
    }
}
```

What I'd like to do is find a way to unit test this code block. I wanted to mock the response so I could specifically set the response codes, if possible.  Could someone please show me a way to do this?

Comment: I have actually coded this by mocking HTTPBuilder, but I'd still like to see what mocking the client looks like.

Comment: what do you mean by mocking "the client" ?

Comment: Something like this: http://groovyconsole.appspot.com/script/760001 
Simply set this mock to your service.

Comment: @Michael I'm not sure what "the client" should be.  It was mentioned that mocking "the client" was a better approach in the question that I linked to, however, I didn't know what the poster meant either.

Comment: @Raphael Thank you. I mocked my solution differently, but your code sample looks much simpler than my solution turned out to be. The biggest issue I had was being able to test the paths for different response codes. Your sample seems to have solved that issue.

Comment: Can you post as answer an accept it? So other will not spend time seeing this closed topic.

Comment: @Raphael If you will post your comment into an answer I will accept it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is my prefered solution:

```
class MockHTTPBuilder{
    MockHTTPBuilder(string){}
    MockHTTPBuilder(){}
    def pleaseFail = false
    def mockData = []
    def request(a, b, c){
        if(pleaseFail) [status:'500',data: mockData ?: "It failed :("]
        else [status:'200',data: mockData ?: "Yay :)"]
    }
}
```

Here's some sample usages: http://groovyconsole.appspot.com/script/760001

Alternatively, you can metaprogram the actual httpClient instance and make it behave as expected(forcebly failing or passing during test-time) but that's a little bit more complicated.