# How to use MockFor to mock client on HttpBuilder?

Tags: grails, groovy, httpbuilder

I have some Grails production code I'd like to test and I've seen some examples of that here, see below. Problem is that I run into MissimgMethodExceptions on the client part of the HttpBuilder. This is the production code I'd like to test:

```
class RunkeeperActivitiesRetrieverService {
    def http = new RESTClient("http://api.runkeeper.com/")

    def getActivities() {
        http.client.clearRequestInterceptors();
        http.client.addRequestInterceptor(new HttpRequestInterceptor() {
            void process(HttpRequest httpRequest, HttpContext httpContext) {
                httpRequest.addHeader('Authorization', 'Bearer xxxxxxxxxx')
            }
        })
        //Do more with the httpBuilder
    }
}
```

I found some help on the topic of mocking the HTTPBuilder here: [Groovy HTTPBuilder Mocking the Response](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9101084/groovy-httpbuilder-mocking-the-response) and some on mocking interfaces in the groovy docs here: http://groovy.codehaus.org/Groovy+way+to+implement+interfaces

Using that code I came to this test code:

```
def mock = new MockFor(HTTPBuilder)
def impl = [
    addRequestInterceptor : {HttpRequestInterceptor interceptor -> println "hi 4"+interceptor},
    clearRequestInterceptors : {println "hi 88"}
            ]
def client = impl as HttpClient

mock.demand.getClient {return client}
mock.use{
    service.http = new HTTPBuilder()
    println service.getActivities()
}
```

Unfortunately my knowledge of Groovy is too limited to solve the exception that is thrown: `groovy.lang.MissingMethodException: No signature of method: $Proxy15.clearRequestInterceptors() is applicable for argument types: () values: []`

What am I missing here?

Answer (score 1):

You're casting `impl` to `HttpClient` - it doesn't appear the method in question is defined on [that interface](http://hc.apache.org/httpcomponents-client-ga/httpclient/apidocs/org/apache/http/client/HttpClient.html).  Perhaps you mean to use some subclass of [`AbstractHttpClient`](http://hc.apache.org/httpcomponents-client-ga/httpclient/apidocs/org/apache/http/impl/client/AbstractHttpClient.html).